# C# Client socket redirect, how to know that?

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server

I have a binary file that connects to my server. In that file, I define the server IP-address like `123.123.123.123` (A).

But now user using a loader can make a proxy in `127.0.0.1` (B) and hook into my client file, redirect the client file IP-address from (A) -> (B) with the purpose to manipulating the packets which are my server send to the client, so they will look like this.

```
  126.126.126.126            127.0.0.1         123.123.123.123
   [CLIENT.exe]     ->      [PROXY.exe]   ->    [SERVER.exe]
```

My server files are written in C#, no matter what I do, what packet I read, it always shows the client IP-address with packet seems as normal as well, here is part of my code.

```
ConcurrentDictionary<Socket, ClientsConnect> CLIENTS;
LISTENER.BeginAccept(delegate (IAsyncResult result)
{
    Socket Async = result.AsyncState as Socket;
    Socket Accept = Async.EndAccept(result);
    CLIENTS[Accept].SOCKET_IP = Accept.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
    CLIENTS[Accept].IDE_TIME = DateTime.Now;
}, LISTENER);
```

My question is, is there any way to know the client socket has been redirected to client local proxy when connected to my server?

Any idea?

Comment: can I clarify the question; are you saying that you have [client]->[proxy]->[server], and that [server] is seeing the [proxy] address, but you want to see the [client] address? if so: that's not really directly possible - the entire point of a proxy is that [server] doesn't necessarily know about [client] (and it probably isn't even be routable), unless either [client] or [proxy] *tell it* in some way, for example the `X-Forwarded-For` header in the case of http

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, you understand right what I say, but the problem is that [proxy] is listening in 127.0.0.1, so the [proxy] and [client] have the same WAN IP. Maybe I have to modify  [client] to know if it redirects or not. It will be easy if socket contains header like `X-Forwarded-For` :D

Comment: any notion of "headers" is a protocol level thing - layer 7 in OSI terms; it isn't inbuilt

Comment: An IP message contains the Source IP address and Destination IP address.  Routers do not add any information to the IP except the TTL (Time to live) which is decrease by 1 as message is forwarded by routers and server.  The only real way of making sure a message goes through a server is to use Port Forwarding which will change the Port number and Source IP address.